# Loop post array to make dynamic

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make this code simpler and cleaner, I am making quiz app, so I have 20 answers. Now that problem is what if I want to make it 50 answers. I do not want to type 50 new answers.

The code works well, but the problem is all are coded in static. How can I simplify this to become more effective in adding questions? I used radio button as its input. This is also the main problem because it does not have dynamic. Can I loop this? tried it before but it did not work as expected

```
public function resultDisplay(){

        $this->data['checks'] = array(
            'quest1' => $this->input->post('quizId1'),
            'quest2' => $this->input->post('quizId2'),
            'quest3' => $this->input->post('quizId3'),
            'quest4' => $this->input->post('quizId4'),
            'quest5' => $this->input->post('quizId5'),
            'quest6' => $this->input->post('quizId6'),
            'quest7' => $this->input->post('quizId7'),
            'quest8' => $this->input->post('quizId8'),
            'quest9' => $this->input->post('quizId9'),
            'quest10' => $this->input->post('quizId10'),
            'quest11' => $this->input->post('quizId11'),
            'quest12' => $this->input->post('quizId12'),
            'quest13' => $this->input->post('quizId13'),
            'quest14' => $this->input->post('quizId14'),
            'quest15' => $this->input->post('quizId15'),
            'quest16' => $this->input->post('quizId16'),
            'quest17' => $this->input->post('quizId17'),
            'quest18' => $this->input->post('quizId18'),
            'quest19' => $this->input->post('quizId19'),
            'quest20' => $this->input->post('quizId20'),
        );

        $this->load->model('quiz_model');

        $this->data['results'] = $this->quiz_model->getQuestions();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('activity/result_display', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

I view page source the image and here are the arrays of the radio button, you can see it on the highlighted one the name

[image: view page source]

Here is my radio button, **Do I need to make this an array? and how?**

```
    <?php $i = 'A';
        foreach($ans_array AS $array_value): 
    ?>
    <?= $i; ?>.&nbsp; 

    <input type="radio" name="quizId<?= $question->id ?>" value="<?= $array_value ?>" required /> <?= $array_value ?> <br>

    <?php 
        $i++; 
        endforeach; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array will be more efficient. You can do it this way:

```
<input type="radio" name="quizId[<?= $question->id ?>]" value="<?= $array_value ?>" required /> <?= $array_value ?> <br />
```

So after `post` you can go throughout loop and get your post results like:

```
foreach($this->input->post('quizId') as $val){
    //work with each value here
}
```

Like i see you can update the controller this way:

```
$this->data['checks'] = $this->input->post('quizId');
```

You sent entire array to `view`. Now in the `view` file you need to specify the key value to be like `quizId . $key`.

Comment: yes, changed it through my code before. Will there be any changes in the controller? the code you see above which has 20 answers? `ques1-20`?

Comment: @Serhei Leonenco - Please see the `$this->data['checks'] = array(..)` can i simplify this code?

Comment: hello sir, your code did simplify my problem, however is using `$_POST` method puts my code into vulnerable actions such as sql injections or penetration? thank you. just asking

Comment: It was just example, you need to use native post handlers.

Comment: over all this is why i've done  `foreach($_POST['quizId'] as $val){
   //work with each value here
   $this->data['checks'] = $this->input->post('quizId');
  }` in the controller as a whole right?

Comment: No, just replace the entire line `$this->data['checks'] = array(...);` with `$this->data['checks'] = $this->input->post('quizId');`

Comment: @Serhei Leonenco - thank you sir! problem solved. this is a very good example. it did enhanced my understanding